# How do I know if I've already done Arena matches today?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I don't want to miss out on the lapis rewards for 1st and 5th match played in the arena, but other than that I'm currently focusing on Colosseum levels just to use up arena orbs without effort.

However, I don't see any indicator of whether I've done my arena matches for the day, except on days where there is a daily quest - and that is also only for 1 match usually, no mention of 5.

Is there a way to look up exact number of arena matches played (for the day)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, regardless of whether you win or lose, you will always recieve a "reward", up to the fifth battle.

[image]

Theses rewards are:

1. Lapis
2. Ether
3. Star Quartz
4. Potion
5. Lapis

This means that if you do not receive any of these after a battle, you have completed your "quota" for the day.

As for checking whether or not you have completed 5 arena battles, you can only complete one more, or check your inbox to track the rewards you have already received. Other than that, there is no way to track how many battles you have participated in today.

Additionally, for reference, the clock restarts at UTC +8.

Comment: That's what I've been doing (checking inbox if not cleared, else play another match) - oh well, thanks for confirmation there's no other way to figure it out without spending an orb :(